# How do I unlock the app engine database when localhost runs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-datastore

Right now I get a blank page when localhost runs, but the deployed app is fine. The logs show the "database is locked". How do I "unlock" the database for localhost?

Answer (score 9):

This can happen if you're running multiple instances of dev_appserver without giving them distinct datastore files/directories. If you need to be running multiple instances, see `dev_appserver.py --help` and look at the options for specifying paths/files.

Comment: Newbie question - how did I get to the point where I'm running multiple instances of dev_appserver? I'm only running one folder for each app. Is there a way to undo this in the app engine sdk/google app engine launcher?

Comment: This often happens when using `dev_appserver` from the command line in multiple shell windows. Sorry, but have very little experience with the launcher, being an old-school command-line kind of developer.

Comment: I went into the docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) and tried dev_appserver.py  --max_module_instances=1 in command line, and it said I had too few arguments?

Comment: You need to include a path to the directory that hold `app.yaml`. (`.` is fine if you're already there.)

Answer (score 8):

Dave W. Smith has the right idea. I had this same issue and looking into the docs you need to set the `--storage_path='some/path'` to be different for each instance of the localhost.

From the Docs:

```
 --storage_path PATH      path to the data (datastore, blobstore, etc.)
```

Also, different port and `admin_ports` have to be set to run the two instances.

Comment: To elaborate: When the dev server starts it uses the default datastore, which it locks, so other dev servers cannot access it, hence the message. So use: `dev_appserver.py ./ --port=<unique port number> --admin_port=<unique port number> --storage_path=<unique path>` e.g. `dev_appserver.py ./ --port=8001 --admin_port=8002 --storage_path=var/api`. Using `var/api` will create this path in your app's file structure.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked, I noticed that when this happens, there are multiple pythonw.exe processes working in the process bar.

Go to command prompt, run the following

```
taskkill /f /im pythonw.exe
```

Restart your application from the app launcher

Comment: Just `python.exe` for me, and I had to open in Administrator mode.

Comment: In Windows, the task manager was showing multiple copies of python.exe task. Killing a task fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So with your command to start the server which should be 
`start_in_shell.sh -f -p 8xxx -a 8xxx`

do include a `-s` flag after the `-f` as below:

`start_in_shell.sh -f -s -p 8xxx -a 8xxx`

Sometimes some unanticipated error somewhere causes this issue. Remember to keep **only one** of the instances with this flag(`-s`) and others should be started as you do usually.

This should make it work.